# When redirect Rails is not rendering html response on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to use this method

```
  def create
    @ticket = current_user.creator.build(ticket_params)
    if @ticket.save!
      flash[:success] = "Thanks! I'll be in touch soon!"
      redirect_to @ticket
    else
      render :root
    end
  end
```

It saves a perfect ticket record in the database. And return the 'show' page's html as response, **but in the browser is still in the same page**.

the response and two request created by this method is:

[image]

My form:

```
= simple_form_for(@ticket, html: { class: 'form-horizontal', multipart: true  }, remote: true) do |f|

#.....

  = f.submit 'Criar Ticket', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Comment: Where is your form located currently?

Comment: If your form is on the same page which the redirect is called upon then the URL remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting remote to true in your form, therefore making a javascript request. However your controller is responding as if it was an html request by redirecting. Why are you setting remote to true?  If there's not a good reason simply remove `remote: true` and things will work.

Comment: I'm using an ajax request, but I tried to remove remote:true and my ajax request was not damaged, and everything is working, thanks.